# nodejitsu deploy of webrtc demo failing to server client-side javascript

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc, nodejitsu

I'm trying to deploy to a simple WebRTC.io demo app (https://github.com/dougnukem/webrtc.io-demo) to nodejitsu, but when it's deployed (http://dougnukemwebrtc.jit.su/) it fails to serve the client-side javascript:

- http://dougnukemwebrtc.jit.su/webrtcio.js

> Cannot GET /webrtcio.js

It runs fine when I'm running it locally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dougnukem/webrtc.io-demo.git
$ cd webrtc.io-demo/
$ npm install
$ node example/server.js &
$ curl http://localhost:8000/webrtc.io.js
```

Answer (score 3):

webrtc.io.js was actually a symlink, and npm and nodejitsu don't package and deploy those (https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu/issues/379).

> ```
> $ ls -al example/public
> webrtc.io.js -> ../../node_modules/webrtc.io-client/lib/webrtc.io.js
> ```

So for now I put a workaround as a predeploy/postdeploy hack that copies the actually file into example/public/ from node_modules to be sent to the nodejitsu servers, and then revert it back to a symlink for local dev. There's probably a more elegant solution.

package.json: https://github.com/dougnukem/webrtc.io-demo/commit/3b1073d5b6af78100dd7e018f4a67b078ca552e6

```
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "cd ./example/public && rm webrtc.io.js && cp ../../node_modules/webrtc.io-client/lib/webrtc.io.js webrtc.io.js",
    "postdeploy": "cd ./example/public && rm webrtc.io.js && ln -s ../../node_modules/webrtc.io-client/lib/webrtc.io.js webrtc.io.js",
    "start": "node example/server.js"
  }
```